# is it possible to use the google.maps api library on the node.js server side?

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3

I am working on google map application which uses the google map version3 api, in particular the utility methods in google.maps.geometry.encoding, such as decodePath, encodePath, computeDistanceBetween, interpolate, in order to compute where the places

In the 1st version of web app, much of application logic is on the web broswer, and now I want to move some logic to the node.js based server. however, since the application depends on google api, I wonder is there a way that I can still use google map api on the node.js server

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible?  Probably, with some work.  Are you allowed to?  Unlikely.  Read the terms of service.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms No.

Comment: Thanks, so I think I have to implement these utility functions by myself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a module like **node-googlemaps** https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps that has already wrapped the API for you. Or, you could use any node module that will help you make API requests:

**Mikeal's Request**: https://github.com/mikeal/request

**Restler**: https://github.com/danwrong/restler

Although, I'm not sure about the utility methods specifically.

Comment: How can I get the google map object from this? 
var GoogleMapsAPI = require('googlemaps');
var gmAPI = new GoogleMapsAPI({key: "<KEY>"});

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS I've very interested in this myself; I like using things like `new google.maps.LatLng()` since you get IDE support (and enforcement), but I've not been able to find a node library that matches the google docs.

What's needed is an isomorphic version of the google maps api cdn. I might try and make one myself, but if you find out any information on this, I've loved to hear it. 

I use the Typescript definitions, which do match, but I can't actually used them in JS - They're only usable in JSDocs.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the way how to load and use geometry library from google maps in node.js But I found a small npm module [geolib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib) which can do some of calculations. I've compared results from the module and from google maps geometry library and they match. I hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: Although a possible workaround for some situations, this answer doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Your comment has no value at all.

Comment: I added the comment because I gave your answer a down vote. The OP's question was specific to the Google JavaScript v3 API and whether he could load that script into a nodejs server. Your answer doesn't provide a way to do that; it would have been better as a comment. StackOverflow asks people to provide feedback when they downvote.

Comment: Clear. The author wants "..to move some logic to the node.js based server" My response gives him exactly what he wants.

Answer (score -1):

**FOLLOW THESE STEP BY STEP INSTRUCTIONS**

1. Run this command in terminal `npm install @google/maps --save`
2. Copy Paste this code

   ```
   var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
     key: xxxxxxxxxx
   });

   function getDirections (req, callback)  {
     googleMapsClient.directions({
     origin: req.origin,
     destination: req.destination,
     mode: req.mode,

     }, function(err, response) {
       console.log(err);
       console.log(response);
       if (!err) { 
         callback(response);
       };
     });
   };

   var inputs = {
     origin: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA",
     destination: "1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA",
     mode: "driving",
   };

   getDirections(inputs, function(result){
     console.log("Response: ", JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))))
   });
   ```

**For Further Readings** https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

Comment: This answer is not using the Google Maps JavaScript API, but rather is using a separate Google developed library that is not fully compatible with their front-end service. The OP asked for how to load the front-end service code into nodejs. I'm still trying to figure out how to do what the OP asked so I can mock it in tests.