# Google Maps geometry library in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a lot of trouble integrating the Google Maps API into Node.js. I'm currently using the [node-googlemaps](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps) library.

However, I can't seem to be able to use the Google Maps geometry library specifically within this API.

So far I've gotten the directions API working. I would like to construct a polyline from the result of directions response, and then see if the polyline contains coordinates.

I guess the geometry API isn't 100% necessary, but it's something that I know would work if I could just get it working through Node.

Thank you!

Comment: If you simply need polyline encoding and decoding, I'd recommend this library as an alternative: https://github.com/mapbox/polyline

Comment: Do you have the code you made so far to get the directions API working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57216131/3407629 follow this answer @TomG.

Answer (score 4):

The [spherical-geometry-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spherical-geometry-js) library ports the Google Maps geometry API, so you could use it alongside node-googlemaps in your code. *(Disclaimer: I'm the author of spherical-geometry-js.)*

Comment: how can I require your lib in node.js, I'm getting undefined and I can't use import/exports in node.js @NotWoods

Comment: How are you importing the library? It should work with CJS or bundlers:
`const { computeDistanceBetween } = require('spherical-geometry-js')`.

Feel free to file an issue so we can dig deeper into the problem: https://github.com/NotWoods/spherical-geometry-js