# Call Google API with no HTML gives error "google is not defined"

Tags: node.js, google-api, bots, google-street-view

This issue is clearly a duplicate, but I cannot find a solution to the problem that does not contain HTML code. I am coding node js to use for a bot so everything happens inside the javascript. 
I need to use StreetViewService but not sure how to call Google API or if I need a module.

```
var request = require('request');

function initialize() {
  var latLong = {lat: -33.867386, lng: 151.195767};
  var streetviewService = new google.maps.StreetViewLocationRequest();
  streetviewService.getPanorama(
    {location: latLong,
    preference: NEAREST,
    radius: 200,
    source: OUTDOOR},
    function(streetViewPanoramaData, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        newLatLng = streetViewPanoramaData.location.latLng;
      }
    });
  }

  nearestStreetViewUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+ process.env.GoogleApiKey + '&callback=' +initialize();
  request(nearestStreetViewUrl, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
     console.log(body);
     // do something
   }
 });
```

This code gives error "google is not defined". I believe I am not calling the API correctly, or missing something.

Comment: First thing to do: Indent you code properly and match all braces. It's hard to tell you exactly what is wrong when your sample code throws syntax errors.

Comment: @tomalak I've edited the code sorry I didn't copy-paste properly. The issue is still valid though.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line you are actually executing the initialize() method and pasting the result to the end of the string:

```
nearestStreetViewUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+ process.env.GoogleApiKey + '&callback=' +initialize();
```

You should set the method name as the value of the callback query parameter, like so:

```
nearestStreetViewUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+ process.env.GoogleApiKey + '&callback=initialize';
```

This should get you at least one step further.

Comment: This is what I was trying first but I thought the function was not executing at all  (because the console wasn't printing the inner function alerts). It's not quite working yet. Do you think my callback function is ok? I cannot access the pano data after execution

Comment: I am not very familiar with the way google maps API should work in node.js. Maybe you can use this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps, or have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955963/is-it-possible-to-use-the-google-maps-api-library-on-the-node-js-server-side

Comment: Thanks for   your time @Theodorus! The google-maps module is for browser only tho, so it would need some additional code to make it work